# Create application link to Skype information

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, skype

I really need your help.
On a Drupal site that I created I want a link that redirects to a Skype user informtions.

I did :

```
<a href="skype:profile_name?userinfo"></a>
```

By clicking on the link, it redirects me to a blank page.

Is that you know how it works?

In advance, thank you!

Comment: It should work, do you have Skype installed in your machine?

Comment: Thank you @pradeep1991singh. I uninstall skype on my machine.
I forgot to reinstall it.